# Gerrit replication to different repo/projects names

Tags: git, gerrit

Under Gerrit, my project is named `project1`. I would like to replicate it to the `server2` where path is `/GitRepo/project2`.

Is it possible to replicate `project1` to another server where the project is named `project2` (*different from Gerrit name*) ?

The configuration file bellow will replicate to `/GitRepo/project2` and not `/GitRepo/project1`

```
[remote "server2"]
        url = git@server2:/GitRepo/${name}
        push = +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*
        push = +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
        projects = project1
```

I need this because I am replicating all my git repo under following tree but they are all in same Gerrit instance.

```
/GitRepo/
        |
         -- PROJ1
            |
             -- A
             -- B
        |
         -- PROJ2
             -- A  (but different from PROJ1/A)
             -- C
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution have been found when I asked to the [very reactive Google group on Repo and Gerrit](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/repo-discuss).

For a single project, it works to omit `${NAME}` and replace by the destination name.

```
[remote "server2"]
        url = git@server2:/GitRepo/project2
        push = +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*
        push = +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
        projects = project1
```

**References**

[The helpful answer on Google Group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/repo-discuss/zVpnXC95UM4/4vEnKesUBAAJ)